# Naming and structure of a function

Tags: c#, oop, coding-style

It's my first time posting here a question so please correct me if I'm doing anything wrong. I just have difficulties in finding the correct way to name a function.
I should start by saying that I'm working on a Windows Phone project, and the language used is C#.
I have a class called Ride that looks like this:

```
public class Ride
{
  public Destination {get; set;}
  public Arrival {get;set;}
  .... 
  public bool IsValid(ErrorLevel level = ErrorLevel.Throw)
  {
    try{
     if(something_is_not_valid)
        throw new SomeException("some message that should be displayed");
     return true; //if it gets here it means it's valid
    }
    catch{Exception){
      if(level == ErrorLevel.Throw) //if I want to throw the exception
         throw;
      return false; //return false, because it's not valid
    }
  }
}
```

I want to find your opinion about the IsValid function. I'm using it like this in my code:

```
public void DoSomethingWithARideOnlyIfItsValid(Ride ride){
   try{
     ride.IsValid();
     //if it gets here, it means
     //that the function didn't throw an error
     rideManager.DoSomething(ride);
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

So the IsValid function can receive an ErrorLevel parameter which can be Throw or Return. In some cases, I just want to see what the function returns, and I send the ErrorLevel.Return as a parameter, but in most of the cases, if the validation fails, I want it to throw an exception with the message so I can show it directly to the user. It's too smelly...so I'm doing something wrong. I thought about changing the name to Validate, but this doesn't make it any better.
Another solution would be to use a property IsValid, which will only return true or false, and a function Validate(), which will return a message if something is wrong, so I can show it to the user. Do you have any other suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: If it is too smelly, open the window and ventilate your room. What do you mean by saying "too smelly"? You mean just naming convention? How about "ThrowIfInvalid()"?

Comment: have you heard about "code smells"? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell
That should be good, but I also want it to not throw an exception in some cases.
And I'm not talking only about the name. If someone else wants to use the function, they would be confused about the enum parameter sent to the function, and by the fact that in some cases it returns true or false, and in some cases it throws an error.

Comment: Didn't know the term "code smell". Gotta have to admit, "code smell" is a good one :)

Comment: Guard or validation functions that throw an exception if the guard blocks or validation fails are not that uncommon, and are offered mostly as a convenience. If such a method is offered, it is good practice to also offer a variant that does not throw but rather returns a bool (or another appropriate indication of "not passing"), since exception handling can be expensive for code that is executed very often or is very time-critical; well, and sometimes you don't want all that try-catch clutter everywhere in your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a class

```
public class ReturnClass
{
    public ReturnClass()
    {
        IsOk = true;
    }

    public bool IsOk { get; set; }
    public string ErrorText { get; set; }
}
```

Then make the return value of the Validate function of type ReturnClass. In the validate function, in case of an error set IsOk to false and write the error text in the property ErrorText.

Comment: I agree with this. Exceptions are quite expensive. There is a reason why the TryParse-Pattern exists for predicates.

Comment: I already have a class like this with IsSuccessful and Message, but I only use it for functions that make web requests. The reason I didn't used it for the IsValid function is because I don't know much about how good or bad are exceptions in clean code. I think I'll use this approach! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. It goes against the language and complicates the code. Exceptions are not expensive, and worrying about it is absolutely a premature optimization. They serve a very real purpose, signaling an exceptional case, and is why the entire .NET framework uses them. 

The recommendation from Microsoft is to use exceptions, and do not return error codes or decide to throw based on an option: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/16/396787.aspx 

See my answer below for what I think is a better solution.

Comment: @Mfanto: Exceptions are expensive and don't suit the 'tester-doer' pattern very well (just read the blog post you linked ;). But i agree, that the costs involved in many cases are insignificant and outweighed by the benefits of using exceptions.

Comment: I more linked there for the general advice, but I disagree with the arguments for tester-doer and TryParse being performance related. There are two very different use cases between Parse() and TryParse(), and choosing one or the other for performance seems silly. In any event, if exceptions are a performance problem, you're using exceptions wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of all the ErrorLevel stuff. It complicates the code and it's hard to tell what the method does.

IsValid() to me seems like it should return a yes/no answer, and only throw an exception if something is wrong.

```
public class Ride
{
    public Destination {get; set;}
    public Arrival {get;set;}
    .... 

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        if (Arrival == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Arrival");
        }

        return DoSomethingToValidateDestionationAndArrival();
    }
}
```

and then your caller can look like:

```
public void DoSomethingWithARideOnlyIfItsValid(Ride ride)
{
    try
    {
        if (ride.IsValid() == false)
         {
             throw new Exception("The ride is invalid");
         }

         //if it gets here, it means
         //that the function didn't throw an error
         rideManager.DoSomething(ride);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Now you can get access to the real exception that caused the error (was it an argument error, which suggests something wrong with the program), or was it an invalid Ride that the user supplied. The code is also a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Does the IsValid really have to have try;catch? Can't it not just throw since any calling method of the IsValid should have a try;catch on it since you want to display the error with a message box.

```
public class Ride
{
  public Destination {get; set;}
  public Arrival {get;set;}
  .... 
  public void Validate(ErrorLevel level = ErrorLevel.Throw)
  {
     if(level == ErrorLevel.Throw) //if I want to throw the exception
         throw;
     if(something_is_not_valid)
        throw new SomeException("some message that should be displayed");
  }
}
```

And on the caller just do something like this?

```
public void DoSomethingWithARideOnlyIfItsValid(Ride ride){
   try{
     ride.Validate();
     rideManager.DoSomething(ride);
   }
   catch(SomeException ex){
      //...
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Or really, what does the DoSomething(ride) really do? Is it for saving? Is it just validating what? It depends on the context. What are you validating? Checking the properties if they are null? If that's the case then you can move those to the setter of the properties, given they have backing fields and move the validation to DoSomething(ride);

Comment: There is a class RideManager, which is like a CRUD for the Ride class. If I have a function CreateRide(Ride ride), then I should check in this function if the ride is valid, maybe even do some changes to the ride, and then pass it to a RideService, which makes the web request for creating a Ride.